# Luigi : Rangehourly Examples

Tags: python, workflow, luigi

Is there any examples available for the RangeHourly provision (or similar ones like RangeDaily) . I've been trying to use it to have recurring execution of tasks . But I always end up getting an error like below :

**DEBUG: Checking if RangeHourly(of=FinalTask, of_params={}, reverse=False, task_limit=50, now=None, param_name=None, start=2017-06-28T15, stop=None, hours_back=0, hours_forward=0) is complete
DEBUG: Empty range. No FinalTask instances expected**

Below , is the definition of the task :

```
class FinalTask (luigi.Task):
    start = luigi.DateHourParameter()
    def requires(self):
            return CleanupTask()
    def run(self):
            cmd='echo "Workflow Completed"'
            args=shlex.split(cmd)
            exc=subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            stdout,stderr=exc.communicate()
            self.output().open('w').close()
    def output(self):
            return luigi.LocalTarget('/var/flags/FinalTask_success_%s.csv' %start)
```

Is there anything I'm missing , which is causing this problem ?

Comment: how are you running it?

Comment: python execute_batch.py  RangeHourly --of FinalTask  --hours-back 0 --RangeHourly-start 2017-06-28T15 --local-scheduler

Comment: Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
python tasks.py RangeHourlyBase --of FinalTask --start 2017-07-31T00 --stop 2017-07-31T23 --local-scheduler --workers 4
```

Notice that:

- You must replace `tasks.py` with the filename where `FinalTask` is defined.
- `--local-scheduler` is just for running your tasks locally. Don't use it @ production.
- There's an error at the last line: `start` is not defined, it should be:

  ```
  return luigi.LocalTarget('/var/flags/FinalTask_success_%s.csv' % self.start)
  ```